# Restrict App to certain countries, Windows Phone Store

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-store

I just want my app to be visible to user from USA as of now. How do I make sure that it does not come up in search result for users from other countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/help/jj206732%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> After you’ve successfully saved your App info, you will be returned to the App Submission Hub page. Under Options, click Market Selection and Custom Pricing.
>
> Once you’re in Market Selection and Custom Pricing, select from a list of countries or regions you’d like to set new pricing for and save your changes. Price changes will be applicable to all new purchases only.

Simply unselect the countries you do not want your app to be downloaded in.

### Note

It is easy for a user to override this simply by selecting another region in the phones settings and then download your app. To ensure just users in your specified regions are able to run your app you must use your own method to verify their *real* region.